# Get Loop Index at Start of OpenMP Loop

Tags: c, optimization, openmp

I have a for loop, each iteration of which is almost completely independent of every other iteration.  I did some initial experimenting with OpenMP to see if I could speed it up.  Using one simple directive, I got a three to four fold speed increase.  The code was something akin to this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(ptr1,ptr2) firstprivate(const2,k,inc,max)
for(i = 0; i < max; i += inc)
{
    float *ptr1_ = (*ptr1)[i>>k][0];
    float v = ptr2[i/const2];
    // do stuff with data
}
```

So then I went off and optimized the single threaded code.  In the process, I discovered I could increment pointers instead of indexing them, and for whatever reason, this yielded a reasonable speed improvement.  The problem now is, I can't figure out a simple way to tell OpenMP where the pointers start for each thread.  Essentially, what I came up with was the following.

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(ptr1,ptr2) firstprivate(const1,inc,max)
{
    int chunk = max / (omp_get_num_threads()*inc);
    chunk = (chunk < 1)? 1: chunk;
    float *ptr1_ = &(*ptr1)[0][0] + chunk*omp_get_thread_num()*const1;
    float *ptr2_ = ptr2 + chunk*omp_get_thread_num();
    #pragma omp for schedule(static,chunk)
    for(i = 0; i < max; i += inc)
    {
        // do stuff with data
        ptr1_ += const1;
        ptr2_++;
    }
}
```

This seems to work, although it took me some time to figure out how to compute the pointer offsets since inc is not one and I wasn't sure how this affects the meaning of chunk.  Further, I'm not so confident it works correctly around the edge cases (when max is small or not an integral multiple of num_threads*inc).  Also the code is much more complicated, and there are direct calls to omp functions, which I did not have to rely on before.  And finally, by forcing the scheduling method and chunk size, I'm restricting the OpenMP implementation's potential optimizations.

So my question is, is there any way to get the loop index of the thread at the start of the loop so I don't have to manually compute the pointer offsets in this convoluted way?

Comment: Unless using something like `int first = 1; ... for (...) { if (unlikely(first)) { start_i = i; first = 0; } ... }`, it is rather impossible to obtain the starting index without using any OpenMP calls and some math.

Comment: What OpenMP calls can be used to get the index?  That might be better than what I have.  It needs to happen only once before the loop though.

Comment: Exactly those you are using. Plus the math.